# Where to get libc.so unstripped library android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am pretty new to Native programming. I am facing a crash in my app which is native in nature. On researching, I found that we should have an unstripped library to identify the line number where it has crashed.

Log of my crash:

```
09-04 10:58:28.708 16198-16198/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'google/walleye/walleye:9/PPR1.180610.009/4898911:user/release-keys'
    Revision: 'MP1'
    ABI: 'arm'
    pid: 15795, tid: 15966, name: RenderThread  >>> com.***.dev <<<
    signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
        r0  00000000  r1  00003e5e  r2  00000006  r3  00000008
        r4  00003db3  r5  00003e5e  r6  e4d46c34  r7  0000010c
        r8  0000004d  r9  e4d46c90  r10 0000000b  r11 18000000
        ip  e4d46bd0  sp  e4d46c20  lr  e8faefe9  pc  e8fa6e36
09-04 10:58:28.758 16198-16198/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 0001ce36  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+58)
        #01 pc 0000223b  /system/bin/app_process32 (art::SignalChain::Handler(int, siginfo*, void*)+742)
        #02 pc 000199d4  /system/lib/libc.so
        #03 pc 0009620c  /system/lib/libhwui.so (std::__1::list<android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::VectorDrawableAtlas::CacheEntry, std::__1::allocator<android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::VectorDrawableAtlas::CacheEntry>>::erase(std::__1::__list_const_iterator<android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::VectorDrawableAtlas::CacheEntry, void*>)+44)
        #04 pc 0009623d  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::VectorDrawableAtlas::delayedReleaseEntries()+30)
        #05 pc 000a1ba9  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread11RenderProxy21releaseVDAtlasEntriesEvE4$_44NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$64c930c5b4139b4fd99ae4f62fbd45a8+52)
        #06 pc 0032a28f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+122)
        #07 pc 000a249f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+178)
        #08 pc 0000c08b  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+166)
        #09 pc 000636a5  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
        #10 pc 0001dff9  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+24)
```

**How do i get the unstripped library for libc and libhwui ?**

Comment: You probably have a memory leak somewhere in your native code, verify your new(malloc)-delete(free), or use valgrind (on pc) to check for memory leaks

Comment: I don't believe you can in general. You could try using [ASAN](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerOnAndroidO) to check for memory issues.